# Discovering pixel information about a font in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Let's say I pick some arbitrary mono-spaced font family and font size in Silverlight.  Let's then render some string in SL using this font.  Am I able to, for each character, compute the bounding box for the character (i.e. x pixels wide, y pixels high starting at this position) and also discover whether a given pixel within the bounding box is black or white?

Comment: You can put the text in a control and then render that control to a bitmap. Is that sufficient?

Comment: @Gabe That sounds like a good start.  I'm also interested in computing the bounding box for the characters in the string prior to knowing what specific character occupies each position in the string.  Studying bitmaps may not be sufficient for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering to a bitmap is not needed to get the size. Just add the text in a TextBlock to the UI but in an invisible way and then get the ActualWidth and ActualHeight of the TextBlock.

If you want to know whether or not a pixel will be set you will need to render the textblock to a WritableBitmap using its Render function and then test the Pixels array.